# How is Mean Squared Error calculated for Point Estimates?

Tags: mathematical-statistics, inference

I am currently going through the book "All of Statistics" by Larry Wasserman, and when talking about inference, with regards to a particular parameter "theta", he states the following.

"The quality of a point estimate is assessed by Mean Squared Error, defined by:

$$E[(\hat \theta - \theta) ^ 2]$$

However, I don't understand the expectation part of this. Is it not just a constant that you can compute directly? Wasserman notes that the expectation is with respect to the distribution that generated the data (with true parameter theta). I am confused as to what that means and how that relates to the the calculation of the mean squared error.

Comment: Hi: Think of it as the variance of the estimate of $\theta$. Generally, variance is $E((x - \mu)^2)$ where $x$ is a random variable and $\mu$ is its mean. So, MSE is kind of a generalization of that where instead of the variance of a random variable being calculated with respect to its mean, the variance of an estimator of $\theta$ is being calculated except its with respect to the true value of $\theta$.

Comment: Hermes Suen: Note that what Is said above is only true if $\hat{\theta}$ is an unbiased estimator of $\theta$. If it's not unbiased, then the MSE = $var(\hat{\theta}) + $  (bias of $\hat\theta)^2$.

Comment: If you denote the data as $x$, observation of the random vector $X$, the expectation writes as $\mathbb E[(\hat\theta(X)-\theta)^2]$ and is thus an expectation of a transform of $X$, since $\hat\theta=\hat\theta(X)$.

Comment: Reading some of our threads about [estimators and random variables](https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=estimator+random+variable) might help you with this concept.